# Setting up custom "Windows Hello" on laptop

Tags: windows, login, webcam, python3, windows-hello

I have a Lenovo 330 ideapad without "Windows Hello" feature. I am a big Computer Vision buff and wrote a python script to perform the same (with face detection). I was hoping there was some way I could add this script for unlocking my laptop. I am okay with compromise on security aspects (at least for now). Is there any way I can achieve this?